# Rails: passing an array to create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have the following array in my view which is the result from a Query

```
<%= options = ['1','2','3'] %>
```

And here is my create action and params

```
  def create
    @answer = Answer.new
    @answer.save
    redirect_to answers_path
  end

  private
    def answer_params
      params.require(:answer).permit(:option_id)
    end
```

How can I submit each array item as :option_id to answers table on a single submit in form

Comment: Start with basic, read guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: whats the relationship between `Option` and `Answer` pls?

Comment: Thanks, but I have found a similar solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116271/iterate-through-an-array-to-create-rails-objects

Comment: @JijoBose Do you get all values with checkbox ?